# Diagnostics Logging for Application Insights Service in Azure

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-diagnostics

We use Azure Application Insights and Generate Alerts and also use webhooks.
We are looking for Logs of Application Insights itself for the Alert generated (This is not the application's log but the diagnostics logs about Application Insights Alert that was generated) as we want to debug details on what data was sent in the Alert's webhook and what was the url (kind of Verbose log of Application Insights).
Does anyone know where we can find that log? Will it be in AzureDiagnostics in Log Analytics any KQL for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Monitor Alerts currently do not produce platform diagnostics logs. I understand what you're trying do achieve but that's not currently possible.

It would be great if you file a user voice item for it here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management